# Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in

Tags: facebook, api

with my app's administrator acount on facebook my app work normally, but with other app I get error: Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. What's wrong here? I tried many ways using different guides but does not return true results .Help me, please if you can, Thank you very much.

My code here :

```
//$return_url = loginFacebook;

    $this->load->library('facebook', $this->app_config);

    parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET);
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) { 
        if (isset($_GET['code']) && !isset($_GET['error'])) {
            $user = $this->facebook->getUser();
            if($user){
                try{
                    $fb_user = $this->facebook->api('/me?fields=email,username,name,picture');
                    //print_r('<pre>');print_r($fb_user);die;
                    if (!$fb_user) {
                        show_error('invalid access_token');
                    }

                    if(!isset($fb_user['email'])) {
                        show_error('invalid facebook account');
                    }
                    // do somthing here

                        $this->load->view('login_success',$array);
                    }
                }catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
            } else {
                echo "Could not log in with Facebook";
            }
        } else if ($_GET['error']) {
            show_error('user denied!!!');
        }
    } else {
        $log = array(
            'scope' => $this->scope,
            'redirect_uri' => $return_url
        );            
        if(strlen(store()) > 1) $log['display'] = 'popup';            
        else $log['display'] = 'wap';
        $loginUrl = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl($log);
        header("Location: $loginUrl");
    }
```

Comment: Is your app out of sandbox mode?

Comment: oh,yes.tks your anwser. it's out of sandbox mode true.tks.